# Retrieving all uread emails using javamail with POP3 or IMAPS protocol

Tags: android, imap, pop3

I am working on an app I want to get all the mail either it will be read or unread. Can anyone help me how can I achieve this functionality?
Here I am using IMAP but I am facing the issue in this snippet.

```
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        Properties props = new Properties();
        //IMAPS protocol
        props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "IMAP");
        //Set host address
        props.setProperty("mail.host", "IMAP.gmail.com");
        //Set specified port
        props.setProperty("mail.IMAP.port", "993");
        props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "IMAP");
        props.setProperty("mail.imap.ssl.trust", "*");
        session = Session.getInstance(props,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication("abc@gmail.com", "abcd");
                    }
                });
        try {
            Store store = session.getStore("IMAP");

            store.connect();
            inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
            inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
            Message messages[] = inbox.search(new FlagTerm(
                    new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN), false));

            for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {

                Message message = messages[i]; Address[] from = message.getFrom(); System.out.println("-------------------------------");
                System.out.println("Date : " + message.getSentDate());
                System.out.println("From : " + from[0]);
                System.out.println("Subject: " + message.getSubject());
                System.out.println("Content :");
                processMessageBody(message);
                System.out.println("--------------------------------");
            }

            inbox.close(true);
            store.close();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
public void processMessageBody(Message message) {
    try { Object content = message.getContent();
        // check for string
        // then check for multipart
        if (content instanceof String) {
            System.out.println(content);
        } else if (content instanceof Multipart)
        { Multipart multiPart = (Multipart) content;
        procesMultiPart(multiPart);
        } else if (content instanceof InputStream) {
            InputStream inStream = (InputStream) content;
            int ch; while ((ch = inStream.read()) != -1) {
                System.out.write(ch);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} public void procesMultiPart(Multipart content) {
    try {
        int multiPartCount = content.getCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < multiPartCount; i++) {
            BodyPart bodyPart = content.getBodyPart(i);
            Object o; o = bodyPart.getContent();
            if (o instanceof String) {
                System.out.println(o);
            } else if (o instanceof Multipart) {
                procesMultiPart((Multipart) o);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e)
    { e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MessagingException e)
    { e.printStackTrace(); }
}`
```

> This snippet is not working as per desired output, please let me know where I am doing wrong it's giving an exception while calling message.getContent 
>   Method threw 'java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError' exception.

Comment: What have you tried?  Where is your code?  There are literally  hundreds of Javamail examples online and on StackOverflow.

POP3 has no concept of read or unread, so you can not use this to meet your goal.

Comment: Hi Max, I have attached the snippet, please let me know how can I achieve the required output.Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you included the java mail jar with your application, and made sure it is the same version you compile with?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest official solution:
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/android

Specially try to focus on the calling in the method `getDataFromApi`. It's very simple, I already implemented this functionality with a few improvements.

Comment: Thanks Jantursky, I already tried this its working fine with Gmail but i also want to connect with other domain such as yahoo,outlook etc